# Trigger Jasper Report Viewer Print Button programmatically

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following IReport class where I have already implemented quit JRViewer on "Escape" Keypress as follows, Now I need to trigger Print button of the JRViewer on keypress of "Space". Please guide me on this if anyone have an idea. (The code should come in the "CODE SHOULD GO HERE" section)

```
public class IReport extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public IReport(String filename, HashMap parameter) {

        super("Report Viewer");

        //addWindowListener(this);
        setIcon();

        try {
            DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
            JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
                    "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, parameter, DatabaseService.getConnection());

            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);

            Container c = getContentPane();

            c.add(viewer);

            //When user press Escape report viewer get closed---------------------
            viewer.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "quit");
            viewer.getActionMap().put("quit", new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dispose();

                }

            });
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            //When user press space print button should be triggered---------------------
            viewer.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "print");
            viewer.getActionMap().put("print", new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    //CODE SHOULD GO HERE

                }

            });
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way you could do that is by extending class `JRViewer`.

The method that is called when the `Print` button is clicked, `btnPrintActionPerformed`, has [`package-private`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) visibility. That means only classes in the same package have access to that method.

The print button itself, however, has `protected` visibility. So, it is accessible to classes in the same package, as well as subclasses.

So, you could create a class that extends `JRViewer` and add a getter to retrieve the `print` button.

```
public class MyCustomJRViewer extends JRViewer {

    public JButton getPrintButton() {
        return btnPrint;
    }

}
```

Make your current code use your custom JRViewer, and do the following in your action:

```
myCustomViewer.getActionMap().put("print", new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myCustomViewer.getPrintButton().actionPerformed(e);
    }

});
```